# Speed up Linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a linear programming problem like this:

minimize $c^t X$
under the constraint that $AX \ge b$.

I will need to solve this linear programming problem online many times. I need it to be as fast as possible.

Only the $c$ vector will change each time. $A$ and $b$ stays the same.

So part of me feels that I should solve the constraint $AX \ge b$ once and for all (even if it takes a long time to find all the vertices of the polyhedron), and then have a much faster linear programming problem to solve.

But I'm not sure how to do this, or where to start. Any help hugely appreciated!

Comment: Many linear program codes allow you to use the final state from one minimisation as the initial state of another.  So if the next minimum is at a nearby vertex, it might be found quickly.

Comment: You might save the last $n$ distinct optimal solutions (for some convenient $n$) and try starting from one that gives the best value of the new objective.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of Robert Israel, I would suggest to solve the problem offline for a large set of different $c$, which are "similar" to those expected in the online optimization. If you store the set of -- say -- a thousand different optimal solutions for different $c$, you can use these thousand solutions for the online procedure:

You take the best of the thousand resulting scalar products (a very fast procedure in general), and, if it appears not to be good enough, you start a reoptimization procedure using the given LP.